# Bind WinForm control to related entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I use the visual studio designer to bind the controls to a entity, the problem is that the fields of the related tables are not showing up.

I know I could do it manually, but I'm curious if there's a build in way of doing that.

As seen in the image, I want to bind to the customerID but there is only the whole table there's no access to the properties of the customer table.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change that the related entity should have the foreign key, then you could bind to this key.